# How to use NodeJS debugging in Visual Studio Code with asdf? (cannot find runtime 'node')

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, asdf-vm

Unfortunately Visual Studio Code doesn't find the runtime executable `node`.

[image: Cannot find node]

But the integrated terminal knows about node:

```
$ which node
/home/user/.asdf/shims/node
```

How can I introduce `node` to Visual Studio Code without adding the runtime executable to the `launch.json` explicitly?

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      [...]
      "runtimeExecutable": "~/.asdf/shims/node" // <- want to avoid this
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is what direnv tries to solve: https://github.com/asdf-community/asdf-direnv 

Did you figure it out? I'm contemplating switching to asdf from nvm and will encounter this, too, if I do.

Comment: @jsejcksn Thank you for commenting. Indeed, that is maybe a very good solution. I need some time to look into that.

Comment: @Robin how did it go? I tried it, and it's nice and all, but still having the same issue

Comment: @FMGordillo Eventually switched to devcontainers and stopped using asdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems VSCode first tries to resolve a Node binary before blindly executing it.
In my case I didn't have a global Node version set, which causes that check to fail.

I simply set a global version, VSCode's checks pass, and then it runs the local version happily, without any ASDF-specific launch config.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked to set an asdf global version for node

```
asdf global nodejs 16.13.1
```